# What would be a good way to resize an image in either node or browser-side JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, image, node.js, resize

I'm uploading some image files (format can vary, though I can probably restrict it if need be) to my server and storing them in a database as a base64 encoded string. I'd like to create thumbnails from these images, so that I'm not pulling down the full image when I only need a preview.

Most of the solutions out there involve reading from and writing to paths, but I've got my data in memory. Is there a JavaScript or Node.js library or technique out there for shrinking files as byte arrays or base64 strings?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try the imagemagick node library. It has all kinds of image manipulation functions. Here's a link:

[node-imagemagick](https://github.com/rsms/node-imagemagick)

Also, [this post on generating thumbnails efficiently with imagemagick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12206217/efficiently-generating-thumbnails-with-imagemagick-and-convert/12688856#12688856) would help, I imagine.

Answer (score 0):

I experimented a bit with [node-canvas](https://github.com/learnboost/node-canvas), which has the added benefit that it is mostly the same as HTML5 canvas.
You could use the same `drawImage` API either with node or client-side.

The node-canvas Readme has also an example on how to do image-resizing.

```
fs.readFile(__dirname + '/images/squid.png', function(err, squid){
  if (err) throw err;
  img = new Image;
  img.src = squid;
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width / 4, img.height / 4);
});
```

You don't need to read or write the image from disk, of course.